# Read EIO error when closing database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling, nodemon

I have an Express application using MongoDB.
I use Nodemon to restart my process when I develop. In order to close down my database connection when I restart my app, I call:

`db.close()`

on the events of:

`process.on('SIGINT', fn ...)`

`process.on('exit', fn ...)`

However, when my app restarts I get the error:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: read EIO
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
  at TTY.onread (net.js:550:26)
```

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this event (example for gulp):

```
gulp.task('serve', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: './server.js',
    })
    .once('exit', function () {
        console.log('Exiting this process');
        process.exit();
    });
});
```